# Wordpress menu links not working with left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress site menu links not working with left click, but when I open them in new tab it works fine, I have installed a theme on it nothing custom developed. 
http://rockstar-marketing.com/

Comment: can you clarify more about the issue?

Comment: Yes yes, I am really sorry if I am not clear, I am new here actually.

Comment: The issue is when I click on any menu item it is not working but when I open in new tab it works fine. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Can you please visit the site and click on any menu item http://rockstar-marketing.com/  you will get the issue clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a conflict between a theme and plugin. Try disabling plugins. Start with WP Super Minify. Its compression methods are a common source for conflicts as can be seen from its [support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-super-minify).

If the problem disappears when you disable a plugin, you've identified the source of the issue. Then for the solution:

1. **Re-enable the plugin and check its settings.** Some plugins have compatibility mode options.
2. **Report the issue to the plugin author** on their support forum if plugin settings didn't help. Disable plugin until the issue is fixed.

Comment: I have tried disabling all plugins and checked, but the issue is still there if no plugin is activated.

Comment: If the issue occurs with only a theme, no plugin, then it sounds like an issue with the theme. Just to make sure, did you also try with a browser that has no add-ons installed?

Comment: yes, I checked it on other browsers and other systems as well, problem still same.

Comment: @imransaeed When clicking one of your navigation buttons, the browser console outputs an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` followed with more details. To check this you can open your browser's developer tools either by pressing F12 or mouse right-clicking your page and selecting Inspect Element. Then open the Console tab.

Comment: @imransaeed In any case, if the issue persists without any plugins enabled, report it to the plugin authors.

Comment: Not enough rep to comment other answers nor chat so continuing support here. Google Maps API warnings and errors shouldn't interfere with the rest of your page.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is issue with plugin you used [jch-optimized](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jch-optimize/) try to disable it and check the links are working or not and you have option to exclude option which js is conflict with theme

Hope this help you!

Comment: it's not working even disabling JCH, I tried disabling all plugins but the issue is still there.

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
NA.j @ maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/3/util.js:209
js:33 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
_.jb @ js:33
rockstar-marketing.com/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (ajax.min.js:1)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)

Comment: Can you please check console?

Comment: I had the same Issue following Plugin was causing the problem "WP Quick FrontEnd Editor".
After Disabling it everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue working with a premium there. 
It was because of a plugin - Elementor. 
Once I disabled it the theme worked as it was supposed to :)

I hope this helps you. cheers.